# cant find the create custom widget in the new project

Tags: eclipse, widget, vaadin

i am new to vaadin and i have installed vaadin eclipse plugin and i cannot find the create custom widget in the `File->New project->vaadin`
and i cant find create themes etc ..as i see these things in the tutorial video and i cant find the visual editor also in the eclipse and i am using linux (operating system)

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed the *experimental* visual editor like described on http://vaadin.com/eclipse. You can first create a Vaadin project from File->New project -> Vaadin project. You could also try to install the unstable version of the plugin from http://vaadin.com/eclipse/experimental (open URL with Eclipse plugin installer) if the stable one does not work.

Then you can check out the manual on http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.eclipse.html to get an idea of how to create a custom client side widget using GWT. This is practical if you wish to get some new client side behaviour not found in any existing widget(s).

However, if you just wish to have a new component without any new client side behaviour, you could extend the [CustomComponent](http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.customcomponent.html) on the server side (in plain Vaadin, without making GWT components), add some custom logic and perhaps combine a number of existing components to be included. This composite CustomComponent can then be used in code as any other Vaadin component.